# When using mult for two large integers, how would I get the actual number from mfhi and mflo?

Tags: mips

Let's say t1 and t2 have integers and I applied mult:

```
    mult $t1, $t2
    mflo $t3
    mfhi $t4
```

Let's say mfhi has a value other than zero. Since it's not zero, we cannot just use mflo to represent the result from multiplying $t1 and $t2. How would I go about getting the result?

Comment: You have the result. It's just split into two registers. Since you don't have 64-bit registers (assuming this is MIPS32) you won't be able to keep the result in a single register.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the result"?